# common practice to manage missing dependencies in helm chart ci

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm, dependency-management, helm3

Imagin one `product` chart contains two sub charts, `app` and `config`, `app` depends on `config`, for example, a `deployment` depend on `configmap` mounting volume. The real senario could be multiple `app` charts sharing same `config`, but only one here for simplicity.

*Goal*

1. `product` chart design need support coexistance of multiple  releases in same namespace, isolated with each other.
2. Need `app` ci success alone,  here success only means the `app` chart can be successfully deployed to k8s, no need function tests.

*Problem*

To accomplish *goal 1*, I think the natual way is template prefixing `config` name with `{{ .Release.Name }}`.
But when in ci, the dependency `{{ .Release.Name }}-config` is missing, so apparently ci would fail. So violates *goal 2*.

*Possible solutions*

1. Deploy `config` before(or during) `app` ci, but this causes extra effort and resource usage to ci.
2. Add `if else` logic in `app` chart to determine whether currently is in ci, if true, not render those `config` parts. but introduce a chart logic only for ci seems foolish.

So is this common problem in k8s helm charts development, and what's the best practice? Is there any existing k8s mechanism to easily **mock** a object during ci deployment?

Comment: Is it just one ConfigMap, with a reasonable number of settings?  Would it work to replicate the ConfigMap across several self-contained charts without the shared dependency?

Comment: it could be collection of `configmap`, `secrets`, etc... here just one for simplicity. replicate everywhere can make changing hard, as i need update every `app` chart.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: microsoft azure. i'm not certain about the exact version(setup by other teams of the company), however, i think this question is a common case, and no need reproduce. do you mean in some k8s version, a missing config map volumn dependency won't block helm deployment?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak `kubectl version` gives `v1.21.9`.

Comment: Could you provide your full helm files?

Comment: it's just like how the k8s official document [projected-volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/projected-volumes/) demonstrates.